# Javafx programming ActionHandler

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

What I'm trying to do is make it when I press the red button, it will set the background red, but since I made it private, my Main Panel class doesn't see the my Button Listener class, so I keep getting an error. Any suggestions on what I can do?.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;


public class ColorFactory extends Application {
    @Override

    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        // sets the width and height
        stage.setHeight(300);
        stage.setWidth(500);

        //calls the mainpanel constructor
        pane.setCenter(new MainPanel());

        //make the mainpanel visible using the setVisible(true)

        //call the stage.setScene
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        // set title to Color Factory
        stage.setTitle("Color Factory");
        //call stage.show
        stage.show();
    }
    private class MainPanel extends BorderPane
    {


        public MainPanel()
        {
            HBox Tpanel = new HBox(25);
            Tpanel = new HBox(25);
            Tpanel.setPrefWidth(500);
            Tpanel.setPrefHeight(50);
            Tpanel.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
            Button red = new Button("Red");
            Button yellow = new Button("Yellow");
            Button orange = new Button("Orange");
            red.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
            orange.setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange;");
            yellow.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
            orange.setOnAction(new ButtonListener());
            red.setOnAction(new ButtonListener());
            yellow.setOnAction(new ButtonListener());
            Tpanel.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
            Tpanel.getChildren().addAll(red,yellow,orange);


            HBox Bpanel = new HBox(15);
            Bpanel.setPrefWidth(500);
            Bpanel.setPrefHeight(75);
            RadioButton green = new RadioButton("Green");
            RadioButton  blue = new RadioButton("Blue");
            RadioButton cyan = new RadioButton("Cyan"); 
            blue.setOnAction(new RadioButtonListener());
            green.setOnAction(new RadioButtonListener());
            cyan.setOnAction(new RadioButtonListener());
            green.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
            blue.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
            cyan.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cyan;");
            Bpanel.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
            Bpanel.getChildren().addAll(green,blue,cyan);

            Label label = new Label("Top buttons change the panel color and bottom radio buttons change the text color");
            label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            label.setTextFill(Color.BLUE);

            setTop(Tpanel);
            setBottom(Bpanel);
            setCenter(label);

            HBox.setMargin(Tpanel, new Insets(5,10,5,10));
            HBox.setMargin(Bpanel, new Insets(5,10,5,10));
            HBox.setMargin(label, new Insets(150,10,5,10));




        }

    }
    private class ButtonListener implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
    {

        public void handle(ActionEvent event) 
        {

            if(event.getSource() == red)
            {
                red.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
            }
            else if(event.getSource() == yellow)
            {
                yellow.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
            }
            else 
            {
                orange.setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange;");
            }
        }
    }
    private class RadioButtonListener implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
    {
        public void handle(ActionEvent radio)
        {
            if(radio.getSource() == green)
            {
                label.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
            }
            if(radio.getSource() == blue)
            {
                label.setTextFill(Color.BLUE);
            }
            if(radio.getSource() == cyan)
            {
                label.setTextFill(Color.BLUE);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: "My `MainPanel` class doesn't see my `ButtonListener` class".  Uh, sure it does. Why do you think it doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program does not compile because your Buttons and the Label are just lokally visible inside the contructor. You habe to move their definition up to the top-level class so that they are visible to others.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;


public class ColorFactory extends Application {
    Button red;
    Button yellow;
    Button orange;

    RadioButton green;
    RadioButton  blue;
    RadioButton cyan; 

    Label label;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        // sets the width and height
        stage.setHeight(300);
        stage.setWidth(500);

        //calls the mainpanel constructor
        pane.setCenter(new MainPanel());

        //make the mainpanel visible using the setVisible(true)

        //call the stage.setScene
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        // set title to Color Factory
        stage.setTitle("Color Factory");
        //call stage.show
        stage.show();
    }
    private class MainPanel extends BorderPane
    {


        public MainPanel()
        {
            HBox Tpanel = new HBox(25);
            Tpanel = new HBox(25);
            Tpanel.setPrefWidth(500);
            Tpanel.setPrefHeight(50);
            Tpanel.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
            red = new Button("Red");
            yellow = new Button("Yellow");
            orange = new Button("Orange");
            red.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
            orange.setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange;");
            yellow.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
            orange.setOnAction(new ButtonListener());
            red.setOnAction(new ButtonListener());
            yellow.setOnAction(new ButtonListener());
            Tpanel.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white;");
            Tpanel.getChildren().addAll(red,yellow,orange);


            HBox Bpanel = new HBox(15);
            Bpanel.setPrefWidth(500);
            Bpanel.setPrefHeight(75);
            green = new RadioButton("Green");
            blue = new RadioButton("Blue");
            cyan = new RadioButton("Cyan"); 
            blue.setOnAction(new RadioButtonListener());
            green.setOnAction(new RadioButtonListener());
            cyan.setOnAction(new RadioButtonListener());
            green.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
            blue.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
            cyan.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cyan;");
            Bpanel.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
            Bpanel.getChildren().addAll(green,blue,cyan);

            label = new Label("Top buttons change the panel color and bottom radio buttons change the text color");
            label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            label.setTextFill(Color.BLUE);

            setTop(Tpanel);
            setBottom(Bpanel);
            setCenter(label);

            HBox.setMargin(Tpanel, new Insets(5,10,5,10));
            HBox.setMargin(Bpanel, new Insets(5,10,5,10));
            HBox.setMargin(label, new Insets(150,10,5,10));




        }

    }
    private class ButtonListener implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
    {

        public void handle(ActionEvent event) 
        {

            if(event.getSource() == red)
            {
                red.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
            }
            else if(event.getSource() == yellow)
            {
                yellow.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
            }
            else 
            {
                orange.setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange;");
            }
        }
    }
    private class RadioButtonListener implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
    {
        public void handle(ActionEvent radio)
        {
            if(radio.getSource() == green)
            {
                label.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
            }
            if(radio.getSource() == blue)
            {
                label.setTextFill(Color.BLUE);
            }
            if(radio.getSource() == cyan)
            {
                label.setTextFill(Color.BLUE);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, what do you expect? That is what is meant by "private". Solution - just don't make it private. Just making it package private should work.

Comment: `MainPanel` and `ButtonListener` are both inner classes in the same surrounding class. Since private members are visible to other members of the same class, being private shouldn't (and indeed doesn't) cause any problems.

Comment: You are right. I was confusec by the sentence "since I made it private".